# What are timer ticks, the unit used by Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks

Tags: .net, timespan, stopwatch

I used to think that

- `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` was equal to
- `Stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks`.

But it isn't. While the latter is a number of 100 nanoseconds periods, the former use a mysterious unit called `timer ticks`. I wonder what those are, and why are they different from the usual unit of measurement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use the [Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx) and [IsHighResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

Yes, it's a pain that "ticks" is overloaded to mean two different things :(

I think it's basically because `Stopwatch` is giving a pretty "raw" view of a performance counter, which can have different implementations for what it means by a "tick".

Answer (score 5):

The `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` is measuring a "tick" in terms of the stopwatch, which is a length of time of 1 second/[`Stopwatch.Frequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx).

Internally, this is based on the [Windows High Performance Counter Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901807.aspx) (if supported by your system, which is almost always true).  The native call is [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886789.aspx), which will vary in length depending on your hardware's support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to see console output ...

LinkedList 500 insert/remove operations ElapsedTicks : 45871
LinkedList 500 insert/remove operations Elapsed.ticks : 141266
LinkedList 500 insert/remove operations milisec: 14.1266
List 500 insert/remove operations ElapsedTicks: 1235121
List 500 insert/remove operations Elapsed.ticks : 3803744
List 500 insert/remove operations milisec: 380.3744

(From which it is confirmed that Elapsed.Ticks are measured in 100 nanoseconds)