# How to introduce an accurate small delay in a task without CPU overload?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, task

I am implementing a communication algorithm to send information periodically and very fast, i.e. 1ms between packs. I've a functional version that uses Tasks to send the packs. Here an example of my code:

```
private void Work()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (!Pack.PeriodicOn)
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        // Time used to send the packs before the interval time
        double tolerance = Pack.Interval * 0.2F;

        // In case of interval bigger than 25ms send pasks only 5ms before
        if (tolerance > 5) tolerance = 5;

        TimeSpan timeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        // The waiting time is controlled by the condition below, if the condition is false, the while loop continues execution         
        // Send the information a little bit before to interval time to deal with the transmision delay
        if (Pack.LastSent.TotalMilliseconds == 0 ||
             timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds - Pack.LastSent.TotalMilliseconds >=
             (Pack.Interval - tolerance))
        {
            SendData(Pack);
            Pack.LastSent = timeSpan;
        }
    }

    Pack.LastSent = new TimeSpan(0);
}
```

My problem relies in the fact that the CPU usage increases to an undesirable levels. I know that I can avoid that by introducing some delay, but,
Thread.Sleep(1) is very inaccurate and the real transmission interval between packs rises, if I use await Task.Delay(1) seems to produce the same effect.

Does anybody have an alternative way to introduce, accurately, delay in tasks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows isn't a real-time OS :/

Comment: Other SO answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254703/thread-sleep-for-less-than-1-millisecond seem to say spinning the CPU, as you're doing, is the way to go.

Comment: Understanding what you mean by "very inaccurate" would be helpful. How much variance are you seeing? What's your system's timer interval (the default is 15ms)

Comment: You may wait the appropriate sleep delay by inserting "Thread.Sleep(Pack.Interval-(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds - Pack.LastSent.TotalMilliseconds))" as the last instruction of the while loop.

Comment: I'm trying to have as small variance as I can do... pretty sure that Thread.Slep(x) wont solve the problem, even when x greater than 15 it cannot accomplish the delay with small variance, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: It should work if Pack.Interval>2. Execute "Sleep(x)" only if x>=1.

Comment: What is the CPU usage for this?

Comment: If I start 4 independent tasks like the one in the example, the CPU usage can reach 80%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not real-time OS so timers are not guaranteed to work precisely. A typical system clock has about 15 ms accuracy. However it is possible to get more accurate events than the standard `System.Threading.Timer`. The Windows API has timers designed for multimedia scenarios that can fire at more precise intervals. I have update the code in a GitHub repo I maintain, [HighPrecisionTimer](https://github.com/mzboray/HighPrecisionTimer), that leverages that API, to include a Task based `MultimediaTimer.Delay` method:

```
private static async Task RunEveryMillisecond(CancellationToken token)
{
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    TimeSpan prevValue = TimeSpan.Zero;
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        await MultimediaTimer.Delay(1, token);
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            return;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that this fires about every 1.5 ms on my system and it can still hit CPU for about 10% when running so it's not a negligible hit on system resources. The standard timer method included in the project are a bit more accurate and efficient (less CPU overhead, ~1%) for running methods on the 1 ms level. My guess is that there is more allocation and garbage collection overhead in the Task-based Delay method.

Note that using this API can have side-effects like shorter battery life. However it is useful for test type scenarios where shorter timings are desired.

Comment: Thank you very much!, the CPU overhead introduced (~20% for the whole application running the communication) is nothing comparing the one I had before (~80% and higher), I can deal with that. In the case of battery life I must test the performance but it seems to me that I wont have problem since the communication periods are not too long and I stop the timer when idle, Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

> How to introduce an accurate small [1ms] delay without CPU overload [on Windows]?

You can't, sorry. The system scheduler on windows is only slightly adjustable (by selecting `Adjust for best performance of Applications` in the advanced system properties dialog for Windows Server or [setting a registry value](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc976120)), but it won't go into sub-millisecond territory. If it did, the performance of the entire system would suffer unacceptably.

Depending on your hardware, I think it *might* be possible to reduce the system clock resolution as low as 0.5ms; however, the minimum thread quantum you can set is 6, which would require two clock ticks to reduce to 0. So you'd still end up with a quantum of 1ms, which is at least twice as slow as you'd need. And, of course, you'd reduce your battery life by ~15% (from what I've read).

For more information, read [Windows Internals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can start many consecutive threads say `n` (n=10 or 20 etc.)(n is the number of threads) after 1ms delay and in each task you can wait for n milliseconds.