# Difference between ElapsedTicks, ElapsedMilliseconds, Elapsed.Milliseconds and Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds? (C#)

Tags: c#, performance, .net-4.0, system.diagnostics, stopwatch

I'm totally confused between these 4. What is the difference between ElapsedMilliseconds (long), ElapsedTicks (long), Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds (double) and Elapsed.Milliseconds (int)?

I have a function

```
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        MyTimeConsumingAction();
        sw.Stop();

        sw.//what?
    }
```

How do I get the correct time consumed by my long running process from elapsed property of Stopwatch object in milliseconds?

Edit: I tried msdn documentation but it isn't anything detailed there..

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793791/what-are-timer-ticks-the-unit-used-by-stopwatch-elapsedticks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> `Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds (double)` returns the total number of whole and fractional milliseconds elapsed since inception

e.g. a stopwatch stopped at 1.23456 seconds would return 1234.56 in this property. See [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) on MSDN

> `Elapsed.Milliseconds (int)` returns the number of whole milliseconds in the current second

e.g. a stopwatch at 1.234 seconds would return 234 in this property. See [TimeSpan.Milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds.aspx)

> ElapsedTicks (long) returns the ticks since start of the stopwatch.

In the context of the original question, pertaining to the Stopwatch class, `ElapsedTicks` is the number of ticks elapsed. Ticks occur at the rate of `Stopwatch.Frequency`, so, to compute seconds elapsed, calculate: `numSeconds = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency`.

The old answer defined ticks as the number of 100 nanosecond periods, which is correct in the context of the DateTime class, but not correct in the context of the Stopwatch class. See  [Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) on MSDN.

> `ElapsedMilliseconds` returns a rounded number to the nearest full millisecond, so this might lack precision `Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` property can give.

`Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` is a `double` that can return execution times to the partial millisecond while `ElapsedMilliseconds` is `Int64`. e.g. a stopwatch at 0.0007 milliseconds would return 0, or 1234.56 milliseconds would return 1234 in this property. So for precision always use `Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`.

See [Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) for clarification.

Comment: With `sw` as in the question, do note that: `sw.ElapsedTicks` gives the number of ticks in the hardware dependent unit `Stopwatch.Frequency`, just like you say. However, `sw.Elapsed.Ticks` (note the extra dot!!) gives the calculated number of ticks in the 100 nanoseconds unit implied by the constant `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` whose value is constant `10,000,000`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for emphasing this subtle difference.  I was using ElapsedMilliseconds in my own benchmark and was wondering why my results were inconsistents.

Answer (score 9):

Reflecting the Stopwatch class reveals that ElapsedMilliseconds is Elapsed ticks converted (and rounded) to milliseconds:

```
public TimeSpan Elapsed
{
  get
  {
    return new TimeSpan(this.GetElapsedDateTimeTicks());
  }
}

public long ElapsedMilliseconds
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetElapsedDateTimeTicks() / 10000L;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct reference to the ElapsedMilliseconds, as asked by the OP. The accepted answer is not using the Stopwatch classes 'ElapsedMilliseconds', this can be confusing as the link had the incorrect text description - now fixed

Comment: Beware, this is NOT right for the current version of .net. You need to consider Stopwatch.Frequency when you convert the tick to ms, not simply divide it by 10000.

Answer (score 5):

in a short explanation from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
ElapsedMilliseconds
```

This property represents elapsed time rounded down to the nearest whole millisecond value. For higher precision measurements, use the Elapsed or ElapsedTicks properties.

```
ElapsedTicks
```

This property represents the number of elapsed ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. A tick is the smallest unit of time that the Stopwatch timer can measure. Use the Frequency field to convert the ElapsedTicks value into a number of seconds.

```
Elapsed
```

Use the Elapsed property to retrieve the elapsed time value using TimeSpan methods and properties. For example, you can format the returned TimeSpan instance into a text representation, or pass it to another class that requires a TimeSpan parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Elapsed` is `TimeSpan`. If you want to display time, then just `Elapsed.ToString()` should do that